# VBA not filling in by element ID

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I have got some trubles with my code.
It works fine on Sharepoint site - its dummy site for me to practice and get things done; but on working site its not working.
Problem is, I have e-mail, got all elements from it and trying to auto fill in on site, but nothing happens
Parsing is going like this:

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate2 MarrPlazaWebForm

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.Busy <> True Or ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

With ie
    .document.getElementById("label-for-pass_date_to").value = dateFrom
    .document.getElementById("label-for-pass_date_from").value = dateTo
    .document.getElementById("label-for-pass_username").value = guestName
    .document.getElementById("label-for-pass_description").value = requestorName
    .document.getElementById("pass_full_day").Checked = True

    Set elems = .document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")
    For Each e In elems
        If (e.getAttribute("type") = "submit") Then
            e.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e
End With

On Error Resume Next
ie.Quit
```

The site does not get elements by id and just leaves them empty

The site code with elements looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="label-for-pass_date_to" name="pass_date_from" class="form-control js-datepicker-from hasDatepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="From" data-datepicker-disabled-date-before="true" data-mask="date">
<input type="text" id="label-for-pass_date_from" name="pass_date_to" class="form-control js-datepicker-to hasDatepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Untill" data-datepicker-disabled-date-before="true" data-mask="date">
<input type="text" id="label-for-pass_username" name="pass_username[0]" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of guest">
```

and so on...

I have suspicion, that maybe the working site is composed in JavaScript and all Id's are not what im looking for
Any suggestions?

Comment: Press F12 and then inspect each element

Comment: Before filling value into the textbox, please try to add breakpoint or using the Debug.Print method to check the whether the value (such as: dateFrom, dateTo and guestName) is empty or not?

Also, please try to use F12 developer tools to check the html resource, make sure the id attribute is correct, and verify whether the textboxes are located in the IFrame?

Comment: In VBA, all values are filled in, but on site - no. Using breakpoints is not helping - its just telling me, that text is there, but its not. ID's are all copy-pasted, so there should not be any typos. The only thing is bugging me is, that in developer mode (F12), the site starting to debug only when i press on text input field. Again - its something to do with it, but im not sure

Comment: Ids looks fine it is possibly that some form of event(s) need to be fired for value to be accepted.

Comment: When using F12 developer tools to check the html elements in IE browser, whether the textboxes are located in the IFrame? whether there is some special container?

Comment: Everything is stored in here:
```
<form action="javascript:;" method="post" class="form-horizontal js-form" data-url="pass/create/people">
```

Comment: It looks fine. Please try to create a new page and just content the input text, then check whether we could set the value of the textbox if using the new page. I have created a sample on my side, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the problem

Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium - I used "InternetExplorer", and it started to work as it should be.

Thanks for your suggestions and responses - hope it will come in handy 
I still don't get it, why it worked out like this - maybe due some security polices in my company